# sudo gem install rails error under ubuntu 13.04

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, ruby-on-rails-3, ubuntu

I'm trying to set up rails with

```
sudo gem install rails
```

i'm using rvm

```
Building native extensions.  This could take a while...
ERROR:  Error installing rails:
    ERROR: Failed to build gem native extension.

        /usr/bin/ruby1.9.1 extconf.rb
/usr/lib/ruby/1.9.1/rubygems/custom_require.rb:36:in `require': cannot load such file -- mkmf (LoadError)
    from /usr/lib/ruby/1.9.1/rubygems/custom_require.rb:36:in `require'
    from extconf.rb:1:in `<main>'


Gem files will remain installed in /var/lib/gems/1.9.1/gems/json-1.7.7 for inspection.
Results logged to /var/lib/gems/1.9.1/gems/json-1.7.7/ext/json/ext/generator/gem_make.out
```

i'm getting many errors currently using ruby 2.0

any help how to solve this error.

Comment: I think for you it would be better to install `rvm` https://rvm.io/

Comment: You're missing some of the prerequisites that ruby requires to build gems from scratch.

Comment: use rvm requirements to check left requirements

Answer (score 5):

I had the same problem, so i did previously an installation of build dependencies for *ruby*, *rubygems* and *rails*:

```
sudo apt-get build-dep ruby rubygems rails
```

.. and then issue the `sudo gem install rails`, and it worked.

Answer (score 1):

Use this command

```
$ \curl -L https://get.rvm.io | bash -s stable --autolibs=3 --rails
```

after this check if any requirements left by

```
rvm requirements
```

Answer (score 1):

Some extra detail.  I had to do things in this order:

`sudo apt-get build-dep ruby rubygems rails`

then I had to install rdoc

`sudo gem install rdoc`

because if you don't install rdoc first (at the time of this writing), you get this error:

`file 'lib' not found`

Then, finally, you can install Rails:

`sudo gem install rails`

and it takes a LONG time, so be patient.